# Swift - not detect the event of moving the Slider in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, slider

I am developing an application in swift 3 with the following interface:

[image]

I have to add some details about the legend. The legend consists of two views (firstView and secondView). Where a default "layout" is 0, until we click on it and that is when the detail of the cell is opened. Bells, a legend like this appears:

[image]

Currently the slider send events are as follows:

[image]

The interface consists of two views. The map that is the view of the bottom ("MainMapVC") that if we make a "swipe" to the right appears the legend of the map "LefSideViewController" formed by custom cells ("customCell").
I enclose the code of the three classes:

The "customCell":

import UIKit

```
protocol customCellDelegate {
    func didTappedSwicht(cell: customCell)
    func didMoveSlider(cell: customCell)
}

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

//MARK: OUTLETS VIEW 1
@IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstViewLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var swichtActiveLayer: UISwitch!


//MARK: OUTLETS VIEW 2
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondViewLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var idDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minRangeDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var maxRangeDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var initialMinDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var initialMaxDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderOpacity: UISlider!


// MARK: VARIABLES
var delegate: customCellDelegate!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


func setupWithModel(model: deliveriesLeftTableModel){
    firstViewLabel.text = model.firstViewLabel
    secondViewLabel.text = model.secondViewLabel
    idDeliveryResponse.text = model.idDeliveryResponse
    minRangeDeliveryResponse.text = model.minRangeDeliveryResponse
    maxRangeDeliveryResponse.text = model.maxRangeDeliveryResponse
    initialMinDeliveryResponse.text = model.initialMinDeliveryResponse
    initialMaxDeliveryResponse.text = model.initialMaxDeliveryResponse
    swichtActiveLayer.setOn(model.swichtActiveLayer, animated: true)
    sliderOpacity.value = model.sliderOpacity

}


@IBAction func swichtValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate.didTappedSwicht(cell: self)
}


@IBAction func primaryActionTrigger(_ sender: Any){
    print("primaryActionTrigger")
}

@IBAction func touchUpInside(_ sender: Any){
    print("touchUpInside")
}

/*@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate.didMoveSlider(cell: self)
}*/


var showsDetails = false {
    didSet {
        secondHeightConstraint.priority = showsDetails ? 250 : 900
    }
}

}
```

The "LefSideViewController" is:

```
import UIKit

protocol customCellDelegate {
    func didTappedSwicht(cell: customCell)
    func didMoveSlider(cell: customCell)
}

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

//MARK: OUTLETS VIEW 1
@IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstViewLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var swichtActiveLayer: UISwitch!


//MARK: OUTLETS VIEW 2
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondViewLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var idDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minRangeDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var maxRangeDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var initialMinDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var initialMaxDeliveryResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderOpacity: UISlider!


// MARK: VARIABLES
var delegate: customCellDelegate!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


func setupWithModel(model: deliveriesLeftTableModel){
    firstViewLabel.text = model.firstViewLabel
    secondViewLabel.text = model.secondViewLabel
    idDeliveryResponse.text = model.idDeliveryResponse
    minRangeDeliveryResponse.text = model.minRangeDeliveryResponse
    maxRangeDeliveryResponse.text = model.maxRangeDeliveryResponse
    initialMinDeliveryResponse.text = model.initialMinDeliveryResponse
    initialMaxDeliveryResponse.text = model.initialMaxDeliveryResponse
    swichtActiveLayer.setOn(model.swichtActiveLayer, animated: true)
    sliderOpacity.value = model.sliderOpacity

}


@IBAction func swichtValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate.didTappedSwicht(cell: self)
}



@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate.didMoveSlider(cell: self)
}



var showsDetails = false {
    didSet {
        secondHeightConstraint.priority = showsDetails ? 250 : 900
    }
}

}
```

And the last one "MainMapVC":

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import MapKit
import ObjectMapper



//MARK: GLOBAL VARIABLES
let showLegend = UserDefaults.standard
let showLegendInformation = "showLegend"
var fields:WFSModel = WFSModel()
var allFields:[Field] = [Field]()
var total_parcels:[Parcel] = [Parcel]()
var poligons: [GMSPolygon] = []
var holes: [GMSMutablePath] = []
var snapShotsLegend : SnapshotsLegendModel = SnapshotsLegendModel()
var allDeliveries: [GMSURLTileLayer] = [GMSURLTileLayer]()

class MainMapVC: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

//OUTLETS:
@IBOutlet weak var dragLegend: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var iconDragLegend: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var timer: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var dragLengendView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var iconBarLegend: UIBarButtonItem!


//MARK: VARIABLES
let layer: WMSTileOverlay
var window: UIWindow?
var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?
var url = ""
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var coordenatesCellSelected: [Double] =  [Double]()
var hole = GMSMutablePath()
var wfs:WFSModel = WFSModel()
var rect = GMSMutablePath()
let start = NSDate();
var polygonSelect = GMSPath()
var posSelecteTable:Int = 0
var menu_vc: LeftSideViewController!



//MARK:VIEWS
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if coordenatesCellSelected.count != 0 {
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: poligons[posSelecteTable].path!)
        self.mapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 15.0))
        poligons[posSelecteTable].fillColor = UIColor(red: 8/256, green: 246/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 0.9)
        poligons[posSelecteTable].strokeColor = .blue
        poligons[posSelecteTable].strokeWidth = 2
        poligons[posSelecteTable].map = mapView
    }

    if showLegend.bool(forKey: showLegendInformation) == true {

        //self.dragLengendView.isHidden = false
        self.iconBarLegend.isEnabled = true


    }
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menu_vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController
    menu_vc.delegate = self

    self.timer.startAnimating()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    url = ""

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    if showLegend.bool(forKey: showLegendInformation) == false {


        self.iconBarLegend.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.iconBarLegend.isEnabled = false
    }


    if !allFields.isEmpty{
        drawFields()
    }

    if allFields.isEmpty{
        self.getCardfromGeoserver()
    }
    self.mapView.mapType = .satellite

}

@IBAction func menu_action(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if AppDelegate.menu_bool{
        show_menu_left()
    }else{
        close_menu_left()
    }

}

func show_menu_left(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6) { ()->Void in

        self.menu_vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        self.menu_vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        self.addChildViewController(self.menu_vc)
        self.view.addSubview(self.menu_vc.view)
        AppDelegate.menu_bool = false
    }

}


func close_menu_left(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { ()->Void in
        self.menu_vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: -UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 60, width: -UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    }) { (finished) in

        self.menu_vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    AppDelegate.menu_bool = true

}


func respondToGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    switch gesture.direction{
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
        show_menu_left()

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
        close_on_swipe()

    default:
        break

    }
}

func close_on_swipe(){

    if AppDelegate.menu_bool{
        show_menu_left()
    }else{
        close_menu_left()
    }

}

//MARK: FUNCITIONS
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.layer = WMSTileOverlay(urlArg: url)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


func getCardfromGeoserver() {
    mapView.clear()

    //mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.4256572451179, longitude: -3.18201821297407), zoom: 5.5, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)


    //MAP POSITION WITH DIFERENTS LAYERS
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.59955969890008, longitude: -0.6421281303940684), zoom: 18.0, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)






    let WFS_JSON = "http://192.168.0.160:8080/geoserver/LordWor/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=LordWor:hemav-fincas&maxFeatures=1721&outputFormat=json"

    if allFields.isEmpty {
        let mapsFacade = MapsFacade()
        mapsFacade.coordinatesWFS(url: WFS_JSON,
                      callbackFuncionOK: coordinatesWFSOK,
                      callbackFunctionERROR: coordinatesWFSOKERROR)
    }



}



func coordinatesWFSOK( WFS_Response:  WFSModel) {
    let fields = WFS_Response.copyFieldswfs()
    wfs = WFS_Response

        for feature in 1...(wfs.features.count) {
            //MARK: INSERT DATA FIELDS
            DataBaseManagement.shared.addFields(inputPropertyIDFarming : wfs.features[feature - 1].properties.propertyIDFarming,
                                                inputPropertyProducer : wfs.features[feature - 1].properties.propertyProducer,
                                                inputPropertyVariety : wfs.features[feature - 1].properties.propertyVariety,
                                                inputPropertyLand : wfs.features[feature - 1].properties.propertyLand)


            for parcel in 1...(wfs.features[feature - 1].geometry.coordinates.count) {

                if wfs.features[feature - 1].geometry.coordinates[parcel - 1].count == 1{//MARK: Without Hole
                    for poligon in 1...(wfs.features[feature - 1 ].geometry.coordinates[parcel - 1].count) {

                        //MARK: INSERT DATA FIELDS
                        DataBaseManagement.shared.addParcels(inputId_field: feature, inputCoordinatesJSON: String(describing: wfs.features[feature - 1].geometry.coordinates[0][0]))

                    }

                }else{
                    for id in 1...(wfs.features[feature - 1].geometry.coordinates[parcel - 1].count) {//MARK: With Hole

                        if id == 1{
                            //MARK: INSERT COOERDENATES PARCEL
                            DataBaseManagement.shared.addParcels(inputId_field: feature, inputCoordinatesJSON: String(describing: wfs.features[feature - 1].geometry.coordinates[0][0]))

                        }else{
                            //MARK: this row contains all points for create a hole
                           //DataBaseManagement.shared.addHoles(inputId_hole: parcel, inputCoordinatesJSON: String(describing: wfs.features[feature - 1].geometry.coordinates[0][id - 1]))
                            //print("-------FIN PARCELA HOLE \(id - 1)---------")
                        }


                    }

                }
            }

    }

    //MARK: Get all group of Parcels
if allFields.count == 0 {
    allFields = DataBaseManagement.shared.showAllFields()
    total_parcels = DataBaseManagement.shared.showAllParcels()
}

    drawFields()
}

func deleteAllParcels(){

    for i in 0...total_parcels.count - 1 {
        DataBaseManagement.shared.deleteAllParcels(inputId: i)
    }
}

func deleteAllFields(){
    for i in 0...allFields.count - 1 {
        DataBaseManagement.shared.deleteAllFields(inputId: i)
    }
}

func drawFields(){
    //MARK: Field All Array wiht all (properrties for field and yours parcels)
    for i in 0...allFields.count - 1{

        let arr = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: total_parcels[i]._json_Parcel.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [[Double]]
        allFields[i]._parcel.append(total_parcels[i]._json_Parcel);
        //MARK: SAVE LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE IN ARRAY
        for j in 0...arr.count - 1{
            let longitude = arr[j][0]//latitud
            let latitude = arr[j][1]//longitud

            rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
        }



        //MARK: DRAW ON THE MAP
        let polygon = GMSPolygon()
        polygon.path = rect
        poligons.append(polygon)
        rect = GMSMutablePath()
        polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 8/256, green: 246/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 0.3)
        polygon.strokeColor = .blue
        polygon.strokeWidth = 2
        polygon.map = mapView


    }

    let end = NSDate()
    self.timer.stopAnimating()
    print("TIME CHARGE 'MAIN MAP'")
    print(start)
    print(end)  
}

let urlSnapshot = "..."
func getDeliverablesForField(){
    let deliverablesFacade = DeliverablesFacade()
    deliverablesFacade.snapshots(url: urlSnapshot,
                              callbackFuncionOK: snapshotsOK,
                              callbackFunctionERROR: snapshotsERROR)
}



func snapshotsOK( snapshotsResponse:  SnapshotsLegendModel) {

    snapShotsLegend = snapshotsResponse.copySnapshots()
    print("end recover fields")

}



func snapshotsERROR(_ httpCode: Int,nsError: NSError) {
    if httpCode == -1 {
        print(nsError)
        print(httpCode)
    }else{
        print(nsError)
        print(httpCode)
    }
}

var onlyOnetime = 0

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    for polygon in poligons{

        if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude), polygon.path!, true)) {
            onlyOnetime = onlyOnetime + 1

            if onlyOnetime == 1{
                getDeliverablesForField()
                showLegend.setValue(true, forKey: showLegendInformation)
                let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: polygon.path!)
                self.mapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 15.0))
                self.iconBarLegend.isEnabled = true
                self.iconBarLegend.tintColor = UIColor.black
            }

            polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 8/256, green: 246/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 0.9)
            polygon.strokeColor = .blue
            polygon.strokeWidth = 2
            polygon.map = mapView

            //self.viewDidLoad()
        }

        else{
            polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 8/256, green: 246/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 0.3)
            polygon.strokeColor = .blue
            polygon.strokeWidth = 2
            polygon.map = mapView
        }
    }
}



func coordinatesWFSOKERROR(_ httpCode: Int,nsError: NSError) {
    if httpCode == -1 {
        print(nsError)
        print(httpCode)
    }else{
        print(nsError)
        print(httpCode)
    }
}

@IBAction func goToAdvancedSearch(_ sender: Any) {
    let advancedSearch:  AdvancedSearchVC = UIStoryboard(name: "AdvancedSearch", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdvancedSearchVC") as! AdvancedSearchVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(advancedSearch, animated: false)
}
```

}

extension MainMapVC: LeftSideDelegate {

```
func sendShapeDelivery(deliveryPos : Int){

    if feedModelDeliveries[deliveryPos].swichtActiveLayer == true  {
        if true {
            print("Not exist deliverable -> call WMS")
            let nameDelivery = snapShotsLegend.legendEntries[0].deliverables[deliveryPos].url_layer
            let urls: GMSTileURLConstructor = { (x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> URL in

                let bbox = self.layer.bboxFromXYZ(x, y: y, z: zoom)
                let urlKN = "http://192.168.0.160:8080/geoserver/LordWor/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&tiled=true&STYLES=line&layers=LordWor:\(nameDelivery)&styles=&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG:3857&BBOX=\(bbox.left),\(bbox.bottom),\(bbox.right),\(bbox.top)"
                print("PETICION WMS DEL LALER: \(nameDelivery)")

                return URL(string: urlKN)!
            }

            let tileLayer: GMSURLTileLayer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: urls)
            allDeliveries.append(tileLayer)
            tileLayer.opacity = 0.5
            tileLayer.map = self.mapView

        }else{

            let tileLayer: GMSURLTileLayer = allDeliveries[deliveryPos]
            tileLayer.opacity = 0.5
            tileLayer.map = self.mapView

        }


    }else{

        let tileLayer: GMSURLTileLayer = allDeliveries[deliveryPos]
        tileLayer.opacity = 0
        tileLayer.map = self.mapView

    }


}

}
```

The application communicates with protocols and delegates. For example, when we click on the swicht of the legend, the class "customCell" is able to detect the event "swichtValueChanged" and send it to a "didTappedSwicht" delegate of "LeftSideViewController", but when we move the slider the "customCell" class is not Able to detect the event "sliderValueChanged" and takes the event to close the view (because the legend on the left is closed with a swipe on the left).

How can I make it to detect the event of the slider and not to close the view?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind your Slider with two Events "**Primary Action Triggered**" and "**Touch Up Inside**"

Here I attached Image for your reference

[image]

and remove left swipe and right swipe gesture on this method

### Method Description and code

#### 1 "Primary Action Triggered"

When You click on slider the method will call "Primary Action Triggered"

**Note : Disable your gesture**

**(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right and UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left)**

#### 2 Touch Up Inside

**Note : Enable your gesture both gesture**

**(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right and UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left)**

Comment: Thanks @Vivek ! :O ! Good explanaiton :) !Thank you! You almost gave me the solution, it has logic what you explain. I updated the code and uploaded images.
But it still does not detect the events "primaryActionTrigger" and "touchUpInside". It only detects the event of "secondView" when we click on the slider and what it does is close "secondView"and showing visible only "firsView".Almost solved, I think that the problem is, how I can Dissable or Enable my gesture? 
Thank you very much.